# Statistical power of an experiment calculation

Tags: experiment-design, statistical-power, effect-size, iid

As titled,I had some confusion related to statistical power calculation.
The calculation is done using

```
from statsmodels.stats.power import tt_ind_solve_power as SolPower
np.round((SolPower(effect_size=None, # normalized difference between Group 1 & 2: min effect size / standard deviation
                  nobs1=None,         # size of Group 1 (i.e. Treatment)
                  alpha=0.05,           # significance: prob. of Type I error
                  ratio=1,            # ratio: Group 2 size/Group 1 size
                  alternative='two-sided'))*100
,2)
```

this function in python.

The question given to us is as follows:
There are 60 stores in an area and divided into treatment & control group equivalently.
The Average Treatment Effect is \$4000. Each store has the same standard deviation of \$30000 and mean of \$200000.
The first part needs us to calculate statistical power.I plugged in effect size = \$4000/30000$,nobs = $30 and got 14.39% as a result(which is the same answer from instructor.)
The next question assumes the previous experiment was done in one week.Now if we want statistical power to reach 50%,how many weeks do we need to run the experiment.

The answer given by instructor simply assumes number of observations = **30*n**,where n= number of weeks and effect size doesn't change. I don't think this is rigorous, as I would assume the observations to be i.i.d, but apparently they are not(because they are dynamic data from the same store).I think this question should be done by calculating the new effect size, holding number of observations fixed.

Or maybe this question doesn't make any sense in a statistical way.If anyone could help me verify how should I solve this problem,I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

On one hand your objection makes sense to me. On the other hand, I don't see how dependence can be credibly modelled based on the given information so that the model could be used to estimate power, so the idea may just be to assume independence for the sake of simplicity. Note that models are always idealisations and often simplify situations. Sometimes this is troublesome and something should be done about it, sometimes not so much, or it isn't at all clear what to do about it (as here, based on very limited information).

In fact, adding further weeks of observations from the same stores, even if there is dependence, the effective sample size will grow and not be fixed, and it depends on the strength of dependence (of which we have no idea) by how much. Note also that in reality there may even be dependence between stores, but as said before, we need to ignore some issues (particularly if they can't be identified from existing information) to be able to use a model that is simple enough to arrive at something.